# how to get latest report in allure reporter in mocha framework

Tags: mocha.js, allure, wdio-v6

how to get latest report in allure reporter in mocha framework, I am getting report for previous execution, not a latest one, can somebody help on this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

delete all the files in  Allure results and re-run the test cases.
it will give you clear report